# What's the static library equivalent to "Embedded Binaries" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, dependency-management

App projects in Xcode have an "Embedded Binaries" section in the General tab. However, Cocoa Touch Static Library projects do not have this section.

Why are "Embedded Binaries" not available for libraries? Is there an equivalent to this in library projects?

I'm trying to move a framework dependency from an app to a static library. In the app, the dependency is successfully included as an "Embedded Binary", but this isn't an option for static library projects. I'm able to build my library with the dependency framework instead added in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", but I encounter linker command failure at deployment time due to "framework not found for architecture", even though the dependency framework has a universal binary targeting the correct architectures.

I'm curious what the best practices are for including framework dependencies within static libraries (without using Carthage or CocoaPods)?

Comment: Wrap the library. https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/convert_static_to_dynamic.html

Answer (score 2):

Static libraries are linked at *build time* to the app binary. Thus, they are contained in the app, and there is no need to embed them. Conversely, frameworks and dynamic libraries are loaded and linked at runtime. Thus, Xcode copies and signs dynamic libraries at build time to the app bundle, and the app can load the code at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded binaries are frameworks that are copied into an application's own package directory structure. The application is linked against them, but since it contains the frameworks in its own package, they do not need to be installed separately.

Static libraries are not a package, so you can't copy a framework to a package. Dependent frameworks have to be installed separately.

You'll have to copy the framework to the application package of any application that is using your static library.